# how to install microsoft .NET client profile of 30 MB size?

Tags: .net, installation, client, profile, virtual-pc

i have  a host pc(Vista) and virtual pc(XP). ON my virtual pc i dont have .NET framework, only Visual studio 2008.

On my host pc i have Vs 2008 SP1 with all of the .NET framework components.
  In Prerequisite window, "Choose which prerequisite to install" i have only checked .NET Client profile.

When i am using a click once installer to publish my project in Virtual pc then it is   installing all of the .Net framework component example   2.0 , 3.0 , 3.5 , 3.5 SP1 which is taking a huge   space approximately 300 MB on my virtual machine.

I want that the client profile should not use more then 30 Mb .how to do so?

Can u please help..
Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're program requires .net Framework 3.5, then the installer will download .net Framework 3.5.

In practice, most potential clients will already have this installed on their computer.

Comment: i want only client profile to be installed which is 30 mb and is  a  prerequisite considering that my client don't have it on their machine. but it is downloading the 250 mb .net 3.0 too(if i am not rong) why is it happening when i just want 30 mb client profile to be installed?

Comment: If your program has a .NET 3.5 dependency, and the .NET Framework 3.5 doesn't get installed, then your program will not work.